# Realistic sublight propulsion

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, propulsion, slower-than-light

I was wondering if there was a realistic propulsion method that needs at most the power output of a fusion reactor which can be small enough to fit on a personal spacecraft, is efficient enough to do trips around our solar system (should at least be able to get far enough to refuel at other planets and in the asteroid belt), and can provide at least 1/3rd of a G of acceleration while staying efficient.

Also as for fuel, doesn’t matter. I have no specifications for what kind of fuel is to be used.

Comment: How long does it need to provide that 1/3 of a G for? I, myself, can provide 1/3 of a G for a split second - jumping.

Comment: Lots more details needed - we don't yet have a working fixed-location fusion reactor and no realistic concept for a portable one, so you need to define the mass, fuel requirements and output of the fusion reactor you have in mind.  As @KEY_ABRADE said, we also need to know the delta v required as much as we need to know the instantaneous acceleration.

Comment: There are numerous potential options. Check out the Atomic Rockets web Site  http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/  It covers just about every type of space propulsion ever proposed in great detail including all forms of fusion propulsion. Very good for hard SF settings.

Comment: Please define what "realistic" is since you're allowing fusion reactors, which don't exist. VTC:Needs More Details until you explain how you'll judge a best answer, what your goals are, and what limitations exist. Please remember that the [help/on-topic] states, `If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question.`

Comment: Join JBH on Codidact what I mean is anything that is possible. It can be theoretical.

Comment: KEY_ABRADE it should be able to provide 1/3rd of a G for a majority of the ride, which will usually be between planets. For interstellar travel they jump into another dimension where distance is shortened by a lot.

Comment: @Epicgamermoment I can't vote to reopen this Q. "Anything that is possible" isn't a useful definition of "realistic." There is no known technology that can achieve the results you're looking for. I frankly don't know what you mean by "anything that is possible" when fusion reactors are still very much science fiction. It's almost as if you're asking, "are there any existing engines that could be used if enough energy were provided?" Except that every engine ever used fits that question. What, really, are you looking for that a Google search for "types of sublight propulsion" doesn't solve?

Comment: Fusion reactors have been proven to be possible lmao. Fusion reactors aren’t exactly unrealistic. They work, and theres ways to figure out how much energy they would produce

Answer (score 1):

One idea is that featured in my profile picture - the bussard ramjet. Such a ship is essentially a fusion reactor, but with a gigantic "scoop" on the front. It is unknown how well this would work, but the idea is that a kilometer wide or larger collector in front of the craft collects stray hydrogen drifting through interstellar space, and then fuses it for propulsion. This means that it doesn't have to worry about the weight of propellant.

However, as I said, it is unclear how well it would work, because of the density of the interstellar medium, the tech required to fuse such raw ingredients, etc.

The vehicle, to my knowledge, would actually be capable of accelerating at least at 1 G - so you could say that this is an early design or something.

Then there are other high level propulsions, such as antimatter, kugelblitz, torch drives, etc.

Comment: Hasn't it been calculated that the drag of such a device would be larger than the gathered material could be used to generate thrust?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I only am reporting that it is a theoretical idea, not going into engineering and such.

Comment: I wondered what your profile was. Pretty interesting idea.

Comment: @WasatchWind you do include statements like "_unknown how well this would work_" which are not entirely true ;-)

Comment: Just adding, some of the earlier papers accounted for drag/other variables that the later ones which cast doubt on it didn't.